# Problema con Laravel Serve [Esperando a localhost]

Tags: php, laravel, localhost

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Laravel. Resulta que lo último que se hizo fue instalar el Laravel Collective en la carpeta del proyecto en la computadora de un compañero. Desde que migré la carpeta de esa computadora a la mía, el servidor interno del Laravel no responde, es decir, ejecuto el comando `php artisan serve` correctamente pero al momento en que entro al navegador mediante la dirección http://localhost:8000/ se queda en "Esperando a localhost".

He intentando de todo, limpié el caché del proyecto en Laravel, limpié los puertos lógicos de windows a través del cmd pero nada, sigue igual. La única mejora es que a veces, cuando limpio la caché del proyecto sí me abre la página de inicio, mas no me conecta con las otras rutas de mi página, se queda igual en "Esperando a localhost".

Vale la pena resaltar que ya instalé de nuevo en mi máquina el Laravel Collective, pero no sé qué más hacer.

Comment: Has revisado los logs de apache a ver ke sucedio, o los logs de laravel especificamente???

Comment: Revisé los logs de apache y no consigo nada fuera de lo normal... Los del Laravel no sé como revisarlos pero no creo que sea el problema.

Comment: Los logs de laravel están en storage/logs, en última instancia podrías crear un virtual host.

Comment: Ok, ya los conseguí pero me parece bastante complicado conseguir un presunto error dentro de tantos logs... Cómo puedo hacer lo del virtualhost?